# PHP if else echo

Tags: php, html, session

I have problem with my code. I have this code:

```
<?php include "../config.php"; ?>
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" />
</head> 
<? if (!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <p><h3>Welcome <?=$_SESSION['login']?> loggedin: <?=$_SESSION['LoggedIn']?></h3> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">     
            <h1>Menu</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="span5">   
            <h2>Header1:</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

  <?
    } else {
  ?>  
          <h1>Error</h1>
  <?         
    }
  ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
Welcome admin loggedin: 1

Menu
Header1:
Error
```

Why error???

Where I have mistake? I think that all bracket is good. Maybe it can be problem with my localhost??? Or I dont know. Can you give me advice?

Comment: Have a look at your source. I think you'll find that the PHP still in there. Did you set up your web server to parse PHP files?

Comment: Is the session variable set and available? Check the file extension.. is it php, html?

Comment: Post the complete source output of the browser. Is `<? ... ?>` being parsed?

Comment: You seem to be using short tags in your last tthree PHP blocks. `<?` instead of `<?php`. Check if PHP is configured to use short tags, or just don't use them.

Comment: @Johan  php is enabled than only it is parsing the code otherwise instead of those result which the OP posted we would have lots of php tags.

Comment: I believe, PHP **is** actually being evaluated. Thats how values are being retrieved from `$_SESSION`. IMO, the problem is elsewhere; the OP hasn't put in the entire code in here.

Comment: PHP cannot be enabled because both the if and the else output is displayed and no errors are shown. My best guess is that @shanethehati is right and short php tags are disabled in the server config.

Comment: when i replaced short tags to `<?php ?>` it doesnt print `login` and `loggedin` session

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best guess is that you have short tags disabled. Make sure that short tags (`<?` instead of `<?php`) are enabled. Or better yet, **don't use them!**.

Replace all of your `<?` with `<?php`, complete tag names will ensure that PHP is parsed correctly.

`<?=` will still be evaluated and parsed regardless of short tags being enabled or disabled.

Look at the source of the page, and see if you can see the PHP code there, if you can, short tags are not being parsed by the server.

Comment: PHP is being parsed, the login name has been printed.

Comment: @shanethehat: Correct. I have corrected. Thanks. Silly mistake on my part :D

Comment: if short tags were not enabled she will get the error at the beggining only.i dont think short tags are problem

Comment: @RishabhRaj: Why? If the short tags are not being parsed, the `if/else` sequence would fail. `<? !== <?=`.

Comment: Yup, `<?=` is not a short tag, it's special template syntax.

Comment: again if the short tags are not enabled the server will not recognize it as a PHP so i dont think it will get evaluated.

Comment: @RishabhRaj: It wouldn't, that's the point. Anything inside of short tags will not get evaluated (namely the `if` and `else`). `<?= $_SESSION... ?>` however, will. Which is why he's seeing all of the markup instead of the conditional one.

Comment: In which case the browser will see it as invalid markup, and not display it.

Comment: For the reference, `<?=` will be evaluated regardless of `short_open_tag` as of PHP 5.4.

Comment: when i replaced short tags to `<?php ?>` it doesnt print `login` and `LoggedIn` session. It seems that short tags are disabled. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

save your page as .php extension